# upload and dowanload Files in ORACLE APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

i have costumer's every one i have to upload mullite files

so is there any way to get it?

i create table with

FILE_NAME
FILE_MINETYPE
FILE_CHARSET

i see many video's but they aren't useful for me

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Page Item with the type `File Browse...`. Then, under Storage Type, you can use your own custom table or you can use `APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES`.

If you use `APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES` it will automatically save information about the file type such as file name, mime type, etc. If you use a custom table, you will need to designate which column in the table should hold which file attribute.

You will also need a button or some way of submitting the page. Once the page is submitted, the files will be uploaded and saved to the database.

[image: APEX Page Item]

Comment: Bravo! Amazing answer, you're a gentleman and a scholar!